# What do the method arguments mean when creating a calendar in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

## What I want to solves

I am creating a calendar with Vuetify.
There is something I don't understand in the Vuetify code. I'm trying to understand it by looking at the sample code on the official site, but it looks like the Vuetify methods are passed unique arguments in the script methods, I've also checked the API, are the arguments to get the time and other events derived from Vuetify?

## Code

**template**

```html
<template>
  <v-row class="fill-height">
    <v-col>
      <v-sheet height="600">
        <v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="value"
          color="primary"
          type="4day"
          :events="events"
          :event-color="getEventColor"
          :event-ripple="false"
          @change="getEvents"
          @mousedown:event="startDrag"
          @mousedown:time="startTime"
          @mousemove:time="mouseMove"
          @mouseup:time="endDrag"
          @mouseleave.native="cancelDrag"
        >
          <template v-slot:event="{ event, timed, eventSummary }">
            <div
              class="v-event-draggable"
              v-html="eventSummary()"
            ></div>
            <div
              v-if="timed"
              class="v-event-drag-bottom"
              @mousedown.stop="extendBottom(event)"
            ></div>
          </template>
        </v-calendar>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

**script**

```html
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      value: '',
      events: [],
      colors: ['#2196F3', '#3F51B5', '#673AB7', '#00BCD4', '#4CAF50', '#FF9800', '#757575'],
      names: ['Meeting', 'Holiday', 'PTO', 'Travel', 'Event', 'Birthday', 'Conference', 'Party'],
      dragEvent: null,
      dragStart: null,
      createEvent: null,
      createStart: null,
      extendOriginal: null,
    }),
    methods: {
      startDrag ({ event, timed }) {
        if (event && timed) {
          this.dragEvent = event
          this.dragTime = null
          this.extendOriginal = null
        }
      },
      startTime (tms) {
        const mouse = this.toTime(tms)

        if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime === null) {
          const start = this.dragEvent.start

          this.dragTime = mouse - start
        } else {
          this.createStart = this.roundTime(mouse)
          this.createEvent = {
            name: `Event #${this.events.length}`,
            color: this.rndElement(this.colors),
            start: this.createStart,
            end: this.createStart,
            timed: true,
          }

          this.events.push(this.createEvent)
        }
      },
      extendBottom (event) {
        this.createEvent = event
        this.createStart = event.start
        this.extendOriginal = event.end
      },
      mouseMove (tms) {
        const mouse = this.toTime(tms)

        if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime !== null) {
          const start = this.dragEvent.start
          const end = this.dragEvent.end
          const duration = end - start
          const newStartTime = mouse - this.dragTime
          const newStart = this.roundTime(newStartTime)
          const newEnd = newStart + duration

          this.dragEvent.start = newStart
          this.dragEvent.end = newEnd
        } else if (this.createEvent && this.createStart !== null) {
          const mouseRounded = this.roundTime(mouse, false)
          const min = Math.min(mouseRounded, this.createStart)
          const max = Math.max(mouseRounded, this.createStart)

          this.createEvent.start = min
          this.createEvent.end = max
        }
      },
      endDrag () {
        this.dragTime = null
        this.dragEvent = null
        this.createEvent = null
        this.createStart = null
        this.extendOriginal = null
      },
      cancelDrag () {
        if (this.createEvent) {
          if (this.extendOriginal) {
            this.createEvent.end = this.extendOriginal
          } else {
            const i = this.events.indexOf(this.createEvent)
            if (i !== -1) {
              this.events.splice(i, 1)
            }
          }
        }

        this.createEvent = null
        this.createStart = null
        this.dragTime = null
        this.dragEvent = null
      },
      roundTime (time, down = true) {
        const roundTo = 15 // minutes
        const roundDownTime = roundTo * 60 * 1000

        return down
          ? time - time % roundDownTime
          : time + (roundDownTime - (time % roundDownTime))
      },
      toTime (tms) {
        return new Date(tms.year, tms.month - 1, tms.day, tms.hour, tms.minute).getTime()
      },
      getEventColor (event) {
        const rgb = parseInt(event.color.substring(1), 16)
        const r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF
        const g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF
        const b = (rgb >> 0) & 0xFF

        return event === this.dragEvent
          ? `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.7)`
          : event === this.createEvent
            ? `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.7)`
            : event.color
      },
      getEvents ({ start, end }) {
        const events = []

        const min = new Date(`${start.date}T00:00:00`).getTime()
        const max = new Date(`${end.date}T23:59:59`).getTime()
        const days = (max - min) / 86400000
        const eventCount = this.rnd(days, days + 20)

        for (let i = 0; i < eventCount; i++) {
          const timed = this.rnd(0, 3) !== 0
          const firstTimestamp = this.rnd(min, max)
          const secondTimestamp = this.rnd(2, timed ? 8 : 288) * 900000
          const start = firstTimestamp - (firstTimestamp % 900000)
          const end = start + secondTimestamp

          events.push({
            name: this.rndElement(this.names),
            color: this.rndElement(this.colors),
            start,
            end,
            timed,
          })
        }

        this.events = events
      },
      rnd (a, b) {
        return Math.floor((b - a + 1) * Math.random()) + a
      },
      rndElement (arr) {
        return arr[this.rnd(0, arr.length - 1)]
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

For example, startDrag in the method takes event and timed as arguments. Also, in the click section that I am referring to while looking at the sample, it is showEvent ({ nativeEvent, event }), and I think the arguments for nativeEvent and event are also wrong. There was also another method called updateRange ({ start, end }). Furthermore, it also takes the arguments (tms) and (event), but there are no values passed in the template, so I wonder why it is working.
The following is the official website of Vuetify.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Event handling in Vue

When the value of the [`v-on` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) (`@` for shorthand) is a function name, the template compiler converts it into a function call that includes the event argument.

For example, this markup:

```html
<CustomButton @submit="upload">Submit</CustomButton>
```

...is equivalent to:

```html
<CustomButton @submit="(e) => upload(e)">Submit</CustomButton>
```

The event argument (`e`) is the data the `CustomButton` passed when emitting the `submit` event. Assume `CustomButton`'s `doSomething()` is called here:

```js
// CustomButton.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      const eventData = { name: 'product 1', quantity: 100 }
      this.$emit('submit', eventData) 
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the type of event argument is:

```js
{
  name: string,
  quantity: number,
}
```

Given the `@submit` handling setup above, the parent would recieve the `submit` event, and call `upload()` with that event argument:

```js
// Parent.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    upload(eventData) {
      console.log({ name: eventData.name, quantity: eventData.quantity })
    }
  }
}
```

With [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) in the argument list, that code can be rewritten  as this:

```js
// Parent.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    upload({ name, quantity }) {
      console.log({ name, quantity })
    }
  }
}
```

And *that's* the pattern you're seeing in the sample code.

### Events

The Vuetify API docs for each component list all events and their arguments ([`v-calendar`'s API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#api) / [events](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#events)).

Given the event arguments below, it makes sense to see the following method signatures...

##### `@mousedown:event="startDrag"`

Event argument for [`mousedown:event`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#events-mousedown:event):

```js
{
  event: any,
  ⋮
  timed: boolean,
  ⋮
}
```

Method signature:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    startDrag({ event, timed }) {⋯}
  }
}
```

##### `@click:event="showEvent"`

Event argument for [`click:event`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#events-click:event):

```js
{
  event: any,
  ⋮
  nativeEvent: MouseEvent | TouchEvent
}
```

Method signature:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    showEvent({ event, nativeEvent }) {⋯}
  }
}
```

##### `@change="updateRange"`

Event argument for [`change`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#events-change):

```js
{
  start: {⋯},
  end: {⋯}
}
```

Method signature:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    updateRange({ start, end }) {⋯}
  }
}
```